# c# web request html response doesn't show well

Tags: c#, html, browser, tcp, webrequest

I'm trying to retrieve a website using tcp and http requests, I added a textbox and a Go button , I type an address in the textbox and then I press the button to get to the website. it works well except it doesn't show me a complete page, for example when I try to reach www.google.com, it won't show google logo and it also keeps giving me warnings about js files.
here is the main part of my code , any help is deeply appreciated.

```
private async void button1_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            using (var tcp = new TcpClient(textBox1.Text, 80))
            using (var stream = tcp.GetStream())
            {
                tcp.SendTimeout = 500;
                tcp.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                builder.AppendLine("GET /?scope=images&nr=1 HTTP/1.1");
                builder.AppendLine("Host: " + textBox1.Text);
                //builder.AppendLine("Content-Length: " + data.Length);   // only for POST request
                builder.AppendLine("Connection: close");
                builder.AppendLine();
                var header = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
                await stream.WriteAsync(header, 0, header.Length);


                //await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);


                using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
                    memory.Position = 0;
                    var data = memory.ToArray();

                    var index = BinaryMatch(data, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n\r\n")) + 4;
                    var headers = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, index);
                    memory.Position = index;

                    if (headers.IndexOf("Content-Encoding: gzip") > 0)
                    {
                        using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                        using (var decompressedMemory = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedMemory);
                            decompressedMemory.Position = 0;
                            result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedMemory.ToArray());
                            webBrowser2.DocumentText = result;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, index, data.Length - index);
                        webBrowser2.DocumentText = result;
                        //result = Encoding.GetEncoding("gbk").GetString(data, index, data.Length - index);
                    }
                }

                //Debug.WriteLine(result);
                //return result;
            }
            }
```

Comment: Of course, the first html you get includes relative links for css', javascripts, images etc. . It is not as easy as you think. There are also other options like "chunked" response, redirect etc. **Better forget about TcpClient**

Comment: Try using HTTP 1.0 instead of 1.1.  1.1 is chunk mode and requires you to send next chunk message to get the enitire webpage.  I've never been able to get next chunk to work.  Try 1.0 which is stream mode which gets entire message in one response.

Comment: @jdweng thanks, I did so,but nothing changed.

Comment: @Eser Guess you're right, but is there anything that I can do about it, I was thinking about searching the result string and add main address wherever it is trying to reach some files in server , but its not doable because "/"s are used in different places.

Comment: Again as expected. Parsing an html by hand is not easy. You need an html parser. So a better question would be about explaining *what you are really want to do*

Comment: @Eser I'm trying to write a simple browser,it should send http request like what we see in wireshark and etc, and then handles the response to reach a suitable output.I'm just using webbrowser to show my html and I dont wanna use webbrowser.Navigate() method.

Comment: @FarshidAmiri And you see, writing an headless browser is not as easy as you think. You are on the wrong track.... Maybe you should explain  *"what your real problem is"* instead of *"how you want to do"* Read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @Eser well I'm not  a fan of writing browsers for sure, but it's a damned course project and I can't dodge this bullet, html-agility didn't work either, thanks anyway man. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @FarshidAmiri Good luck with your project. Most of the time, problem is extracting some data from an html page and the solution doesn't need to write a browser... See my link about XY-problem.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check status.  A good status is 200 Done.  Also check http version.  It may be 1.0 but you need to send another request if you are not getting 200 Done.